# Should I use a TBO or a SSBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, textures

I'm making a voxel engine with OpenGL and I encountered something that I'm trying to explain.

I was using 1 SSBO per chunk in my world to store blocks informations (Position, block_type). Every chunks of my world (About 16000 chunks for a medium sized world) store 4096 GLuint (4 uint8_t packed as a GLuint). My RAM was 578 MB, and my VRAM 480 MB.

I tried to use a TBO (With a fixed size of 4096 GLuint instead of rescaling on need) instead a SSBO and I benchmarked 2000MB on RAM and my VRAM 726MB.

GPU core clock seems (I can't be sure about that) being more stable with TBO.

(Benchmarks done with GPU-Z soft)

- Is there any reason to use TBO over SSBO ?

My idea behind this is that I allocate a fixed size for my data when I  use the TBO. With my SSBO I make this size variable. Should I prefer having a big RAM and VRAM all the time but stable, or a lighter RAM/VRAM but non-stable ?

By the way, I'm getting a lots of errors when I use a SSBO (`Buffer performance warning: Buffer object 13006 (bound to GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) is being copied/moved from VIDEO memory to SYSTEM HEAP memory.`)

I also got this when I try to resize my TBO size/data `Buffer performance warning: Buffer object 200 (bound to GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) may be reconfiguredfor better performance.  Recent usage of this buffer object has triggered a stall.  The driver had to wait for one buffer object operation to complete before it could execute another.`

Comment: Never reallocate a buffer object with a different size. Basically, never reallocate a buffer object *period*; use immutable storage buffers and invalidation if that's what you're after.

Comment: Ok, so TBO is a bad idea for that kind of buffer (Varrying size buffer). Is SSBO a better choice, or should I use something else ? By the way my code works, with TBO and SSBO, the reallocation seems working but I get tons of errors

Comment: There's no such thing as a "TBO" or an "SSBO". There are just "buffer objects" and how you use them. You could use the same buffer object *at the same time* as a buffer texture and as a storage buffer, and the API wouldn't care. Don't change the size of a buffer *regardless*.

Comment: Well, let's say I shouldn't use a "buffer object", how can I store a varying amount of data ? Otherwise, I can also use a "buffer object" and fix his size to 4096, but is it a good practice to use more RAM/VRAM than necessary ?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object Says that I can create a buffer object and resize it, otherwise I can't resize it if I make it immutable with glBufferStorage (Which isn't my case)